# How to connect SQL Server using different port in .NET Core?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, asp.net-core, tcp

In my ASP.NET Core app, I have the following connection string that uses default SQL Server port 1433. However, I want to connect the same database by using an alias that let me also connect via another port e.g. 2222. So, is it possible to connect using both of the ports by adding an alias or do I have to change the default port to the new port? I also tried to update port number in SQL Server Configuration Manager, but I cannot connect even if just using it. So, how can I connect to the same databse via different port?

```
"MyConnection": "Server=localhost,2222;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;
    User Id=demouser;Password=****;"
```

I am trying to connect via SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Is the idea **to connect SQL Server database via a different port** is not a good idea? Does anybody else have tried ever before?

Comment: Each network interface can listen on a single port. You can't have SQL Server listen on more than one port at the same time for the same interface (e.g. for 127.0.0.1) unless you assign multiple IP addresses to the interface. This looks like an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Edit your question to explain why you want to do this.

Comment: Ok, what about changing default port to e.g. 2222 ? Then I think I can use this port instead of 1433, right?

Comment: Yes, you can change the default port and specify that in the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Select the SQL Server Network Configuration.
3. Select from the list the instance you want to configure to listen to
   on a specific port.
4. To change the port assignment right-click on the TCP/IP protocol and
   select Properties.
5. Click on the IP Addresses tab.
6. Specify the port number you want to use instead of 1433 by entering the preferred port number. Also, turn off the dynamical port number setting by removing the “0” mark in the TCP Dynamic Ports field.
7. In order to finish the adjustment, select SQL Server Services, click on SQL Server and restart it.

To open **SQL Server Configuration Manager**, on the Start Page, type SQLServerManager13.msc (for SQL Server 2016 (13.x)). For other versions of SQL Server, replace 13 with the corresponding number. Clicking SQLServerManager13.msc opens the Configuration Manager.

Comment: Perfect explanation. By the way, just applying these setting to **IpAll* section would be enough.